# Getting remote debugging set up with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to set up remote debugging with PhantomJS, without much luck. I am following the instructions at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting. I have a little program named `debug.js`:

```
var system  = require('system' ), fs = require('fs'), webpage = require('webpage');

(function(phantom){
    var page=webpage.create();

    function debugPage(){
        console.log("Refresh a second debugger-port page and open a second webkit inspector for the target page.");
        console.log("Letting this page continue will then trigger a break in the target page.");
        debugger; // pause here in first web browser tab for steps 5 & 6
        page.open(system.args[1]);
        page.evaluateAsync(function() {
            debugger; // step 7 will wait here in the second web browser tab
        });
    }
    debugPage();
}(phantom));
```

Now I run this from the command line:

```
$ phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9001 --remote-debugger-autorun=yes debug.js my.xhtml
```

The `console.log` messages are now displayed in the shell window. I open a browser page to `localhost:9001`. It is at this point that the documentation says "get first web inspector for phantom context" However, I see only a single entry for `about:blank`. When I click on that, I get an inspector for the irrelevant about:blank page, with the URL `http://localhost:9001/webkit/inspector/inspector.html?page=1`. The documentation talks about executing `__run()`, but I can't seem to get to the page where I would do that; `about:html` seems to contina a `__run()` which is a no-op.

FWIW, I am using PhantomJS 1.9.1 under W8.

What am I missing?

Comment: I use [this](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html) to forward a local port to the remote webserver port instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The documentation says :

> To run your script, simply enter the __run() command in the Web
>   Inspector Console.

`__run()` is not a no-op but just a wrapper to your script. You need to select  Console tab first and then enter `__run()` in the command window. If you are familiar with Chrome, it's fairly the same as for developpers tool.

[image: debug console]

Comment: You can also do --remote-debugger-autorun=yes according to https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks! Damn the _double underscore_ before __run() can't be easily seen on the troubleshooting documentation page... http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html

Comment: I'm keep getting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: __run is not defined(…)"

Comment: When I click on the js file I want to test I cannot exute `__run()`, look [here](https://i.imgur.com/D2Vlw3I.png). Chrome v64.x
The cursor just jumps into a new line...?!

Answer (score 22):

To debug a script, start phantomjs like so:

```
phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 hello.js
```

Here's a super simple test script that works (hello.js). Note that you should put `debugger;` at the top of your script, or wherever in your script you want to break into the debugger.

#### hello.js

```
debugger;

for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
  console.log('debugging in phantom js:' + i);
}

phantom.exit();
```

Now just load the following url in your browser:

http://127.0.0.1:9000/

Then you'll see a link listed in the browser page

```
about:blank
```

Click on it, and then you'll see a whole page that looks like the Chrome Inspector. Click on the "Console" button in the toolbar that's in this page (not the console of Chrome or Safari that you're used to using).

Now, in that console type `__run()` and hit enter. Your script will display and start debugging!

Answer (score 13):

I had problems getting debugging to work on Mac using Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit). I got the debugger to open on localhost:9000 (127.0.0.1:9000 didn't work for me) but after entering __run() (yes, with double underscore), there was no response. I could see other js files under Sources, mine was listed but was empty. (I did enable debugging in chrome)

I tried the same on safari and it all worked as advertised.

UPDATE for Chrome: (from Thiago Fernandes below): Apparently the issue is caused by the Chrome not accepting the enter key, so the workaround is to evaluate this function inside chrome console, to get the enterKey working:

```
function isEnterKey(event) { return (event.keyCode !== 229 && event.keyIdentifier === "Enter") || event.keyCode === 13; }
```

Comment: On chrome a workaround is needed https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12864#issuecomment-279612178

Comment: Thanks Thiago but what is the workaround other than install an old version of chrome? In which case I will just use safari.

Comment: The workaround is to evaluate this function inside chrome console, so the enterKey get working: ```function isEnterKey(event) {
       return (event.keyCode !== 229 && event.keyIdentifier === "Enter") || event.keyCode === 13;
    }```

Comment: Thanks for this - for the longest time I couldn't tell what was wrong and didn't even realize that `__run()` wasn't actually getting executed.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the `__run()` would not be executed in the console.
If this is the same issue you have, read on....

**Open PowerShell and execute the script:**

```
cls
# we go to the folder where our test.js script resides
cd "C:\Users\xxx\Phantomjs.Console"
phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 --remote-debugger-autorun=yes test.js
```

1. Open your Chrome browser and go to
2. http://localhost:9000
3. Click on your, in my case test.js file.
4. Switch to the Sources tab!
5. **Execute `__run()` under Watch Expressions**!

Put a `debugger` statement in your script for debugging!

[image]

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!