# What is wrong with my PhantomJS remote debugging attempt?

Tags: google-chrome, phantomjs, javascript-debugger

I've followed the instructions here:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting

And I've seen the SO here:

[Getting remote debugging set up with PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573249/getting-remote-debugging-set-up-with-phantomjs)

But I can't for the life of me get remote debugging with PhantomJS to work.  Here is what I've tried:

```
[ubuntu:phantom]$ phantomjs --version
1.9.1
[ubuntu:phantom]$ phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9001 test.js &
[1] 14037
[ubuntu:phantom]$ sudo netstat -pntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9418            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1075/git-daemon 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5038          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1466/asterisk   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1629/apache2    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1466/asterisk   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1089/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      968/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1363/beam.smp   
tcp6       0      0 :::9418                 :::*                    LISTEN      1075/git-daemon 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      968/cupsd       
[ubuntu:phantom]$ google-chrome localhost:9001
Created new window in existing browser session.
[ubuntu:phantom]$
[ubuntu:phantom]$ nc localhost 9001
```

The above (unsurprisingly) opens up Chrome with a `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:9001`.  Shouldn't I see an open port on 9001?  From what I can gather, Chrome should connect to a (possibly) blank page that I just run `__run()` on in the JS console.  But as it stands, nothing is getting opened up... I can't even netcat to it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm kindof stuck on the same

Comment: I am getting the exact same but in Windows 10 with PJS 2.1.1 - netstat -abno yields nothing listening on the specified port

Answer (score 0):

Run phantomjs as sudo seems to do the trick